# Bold/Strong - HTML5 equivalent?

Tags: html

Throughout the text and the titles on my webpage I need to make certain words bold and others need to be highlighted in a color.

I know before I would have used a

```
<b>
```

or perhaps a

```
<strong>
```

What is the HTML5 markup practice?

Also, do I need different markup for a bold word compared with a word that is just highlighted? Would a styled span suffice?

```
This is <span class="highlight">highlighted</span> and this is <b>bold!</b>
```

And what should I do in titles:

```
<h1>The title is <b>awesome</b></h1>
```

Comment: [This article](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/) may be helpful

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 practices are all about semantics. If your bold text is bold because you want to place a strong emphasis on that text, you should use [`<strong>`](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/). If your highlighted text is highlighted because it's something you want to mark to draw attention to it, try the [`<mark>`](http://html5doctor.com/draw-attention-with-mark/) element. Style those elements as you wish.

```html
You will <strong>probably</strong> find most browsers 
have quite sensible defaults for <mark>styling these 
elements</mark>.
```